# How to run a service in background while the phone is calling or ringing?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the phone call state in a service that runs in background, but when I dial and call, the service getting stop, after i finish calling the service runs again.

```
telephonyManager.listen(new MyPhoneListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

private class MyPhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                callState = "ringing";
                Log.d("xxx", " ----------  phone ringing  " );
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                callState = "active";
                Log.d("xxx", " ----------  phone is active  " );
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                callState = "idle";
                Log.d("xxx", " ----------  phone is idle  " );
                break;
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: I Don't think its possible, Conventionally. I think the only way you could possibly do this is with a hook into the system files. Essentially a hack. Xposed framework might be the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by running the service in foreground.

in onCreate() method

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My Awesome App")
            .setContentText("Doing some work...")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

startForeground(1337, notification);
```